# Creating folders from the Open File dialog

Tags: applications, ms-office

I need to know how to create client file folders and reference or matter subfolders to be saved within each client folder from within the Open File dialog.

For example, "Smith Manufacturing Corp." would be the master client folder. Within that folder, I would like to create subfolders for each matter the lawyer is addressing for that client, for example: "Agreement with Jones Demolition Co." or "Purchase of Main Street Property" and so on.  I was able to do that quite easily with Microsoft Word on my PC.

Folder structure diagram:

```
- Smith Manufacturing Corp
  + Agreement with Jones Demolition Co.
  + Purchase of Main Street Property
```

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done from the Open dialog on the Mac. It, however, *can* be done from the "Save" dialog.

Enter the "Save" dialog (in Word, it's usually shown as a sheet). If you don't see the file tree, click the down-arrow next to the filename box (it's circled in the below image).

[image: A collapsed Save As sheet with the expand arrow circled. (VoiceOver refers to the expand arrow as a "disclosure checkbox".)]

In the expanded window, navigate to the folder where you have your client information. To make a new folder, click the "New Folder" button in the lower-left of the sheet (again, circled in the below image).

[image: An expanded Save As sheet with the New Folder button circled.]

(Screenshot examples from Word 2011.)

Comment: Quite a bit I think as it is the first step in knowing basic formation of what I need: master folder with subfolders and documents stored within those subfolders (i.e. correspondence, agreements, etc. ...or individual documents as in Letter to D. Jones 07-10-12).  I will have to give these instructions a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with macOS's built in capabilities, but you can do it with recent versions (v5.1) of [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/)